# Read value from dictionary when I have key

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have passed to template dictionary parameters like

```
parameters={
'value':'some_value',
'style':{}
}
```

and inside template I need to read **some_value**

```
src="{{value['value']}}"
```

How to read that value, because I try like above but I got error **Could not parse the remainder** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django templates use the syntax `{{ dictvar.key }}` to perform lookups, see the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/). So in your case, this would be `{{ value.value }}`